# Android Emulator (AVD) Crash reason: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting the following error when I start an emulator.

Already tried to delete everything (including .android, avd, sdk folders) and reinstalled Studio, SDK, Nvidia Driver but nothing of it helped

Windows 11

Studio version:

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 6
```

Error during an emulator launch:

[image]

```
Operating system: Windows NT
                  10.0.22631 3007
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 158 stepping 10
     6 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
Crash address: 0x234f114d878
Process uptime: 7 seconds

Thread 35 (crashed)
 0  libgfxstream_backend.dll + 0xdc9eb
 
    rax = 0x00007ff82003c990   rdx = 0x00000233e9bfbbc0
    rcx = 0x000001aee43b34d0   rbx = 0x000001aee61d3ba8
    rsi = 0xffff8800103ff5f0   rdi = 0x00000234f114d860
    rbp = 0x0000000000000004   rsp = 0x0000002dd25ff590
     r8 = 0xffff8800103ff5f0    r9 = 0x00007ff6a7657501
    r10 = 0x00007ff8c9bf0000   r11 = 0x0000000000000020
    r12 = 0x0000000000000000   r13 = 0x0000000000000020
    r14 = 0x0000000000000004   r15 = 0x0000000000000004
    rip = 0x00007ff82003c9eb
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context

    Stack contents:
     0000002dd25ff590 18 7a 7a 4b 00 00 00 00 50 f6 5f d2 2d 00 00 00  .zzK....P._.-...
     0000002dd25ff5a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0000002dd25ff5b0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e1 ea 32 a5 f6 7f 00 00  ..........2.....
    Possible instruction pointers:

 1  qemu-system-x86_64.exe + 0x1eae1
 
    rsp = 0x0000002dd25ff5c0   rip = 0x00007ff6a532eae1
    Found by: stack scanning

    Stack contents:
     0000002dd25ff5c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0000002dd25ff5d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 51 b4 6d a5 f6 7f 00 00  ........Q.m.....
    Possible instruction pointers:

 2  qemu-system-x86_64.exe + 0x3cb451
 
    rsp = 0x0000002dd25ff5e0   rip = 0x00007ff6a56db451
    Found by: stack scanning

    Stack contents:
     0000002dd25ff5e0 20 00 00 00 af 01 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ....... .......
     0000002dd25ff5f0 a8 3b 1d e6 ae 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .;..............
     0000002dd25ff600 a0 38 1d e6 ae 01 00 00 99 b0 3b a5 f6 7f 00 00  .8........;.....
    Possible instruction pointers:

 3  qemu-system-x86_64.exe + 0xab099
 
    rsp = 0x0000002dd25ff610   rip = 0x00007ff6a53bb099
    Found by: stack scanning

    Stack contents:
     0000002dd25ff610 ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0000002dd25ff620 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
     0000002dd25ff630 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 a4 3d a5 f6 7f 00 00  ........d.=.....
    Possible instruction pointers:
```

Interesting that it doesn't detect GPU... don't know if it's the main issue here

I tried `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -gpu host` but still `GPU: UNKNOWN, Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ`

Comment: having the same issue, started since 2 days ago.

Comment: Same for me. Took off the recent windows update and this had no effect

Comment: having the same problem here